# Call an foreign API from a Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) Project (**NOT** ASP.Net Core, hosted)

Tags: c#, http-post, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor WebAssembly-App (WASM) as a PWA. 
It is configured for HTTPS and **NOT** ASP.NET Core, hosted.

The Code I was used is tested in a Console-Version and worked fine.

```cs
public void PostOnApi()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GlobalData.userpassword);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
       "Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{GlobalData.username}:{GlobalData.password}"))
    );
        
    ClassForJSON InstanceOfClassForJSON = new ClassForJSON();
    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
        InstanceOfClassForJSON, 
        JsonOptions
    );

    StringContent content = new StringContent(
        jsonString
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json"
    );

    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(
        GlobalData.baseAdressOfApi,
        content
    ).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        object ResponseContent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(
            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result,
            JsonOptions
        );
        string tempResponse = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
            ResponseContent, 
            new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true, WriteIndented = true }
        );

        ClassForResponseJSON InstanceOfClassForResponseJSON = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClassForResponseJSON>(tempResponse)!;
        string jsonResponse = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
            InstanceOfClassForResponse,
            new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true, WriteIndented = true }
        );
        Console.WriteLine("[Success]: API-Call successful");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[Error]: API-Call -> Validation? Authentification?");
    }
}
```

If I now call this function in the @code part of the page (API-Call.razor in the Pages-Folder) a Cors Error was thrown.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://[Adress]' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

It can fixed with the following code-line:

```cs
WebAssemblyHttpRequestMessageExtensions.SetBrowserRequestMode(httpRequestMessage, BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);
```

when my function above is changed to a HttpRequestMessage:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(
    jsonString,
    Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/json"
);

HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage{
    RequestUri = new Uri(GlobalData.baseAdressOfApi);
    Content = content,
    Method = HttpMethod.Post 
};

WebAssemblyHttpRequestMessageExtensions.SetBrowserRequestMode(httpRequestMessage, BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync();
var responeContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But now the Header has not the `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` that I was set in the `StringContent content`. I think this is because, now the `content` (Variable) is set to the body-Part of the HttpRequestMessage, is this correct?

---

Now my real question`s:

How do I have to modify my code, or which classes are must to use to Set the API-Call and get a Response back, when the API needs (application/json) and the Serialized-Class as Content.

How can I influence the RequestHeader(s)?
None of modification in the header-object are appears in the outgoing API-Call (tested with NetCat on a local Port)

Answer (score 0):

I think that, to influence the Response header, you need to have access to the API, which then can be configured to accept specific Headers by specifying them in the
Access-Control-Allow-Headers properties

> context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
> "Content-Type, Accept");

Where context is HttpContext.

But if you don't have access to the out of origin API, I think the only way is to use a proxy on the origin, but maybe someone knows a way.